# maven project running problem

Tags: maven

How To resulve this problem

i have update my java version to java6u23  but it will still create problem so what should i do

i dont know much more about maven

[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn  -rf :mediaPlayer

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a dependency for jna-3.2.4
This isn't available on the central maven repo http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/
But you can find it in the **java.net** repo http://download.java.net/maven/2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.4/

Make sure that you have the **java.net** repo defined to your maven build.
This can be done iether in your pom, or in the settings.xml in your user home/.m2 directory.